# Why is my broken stored procedure being dropped?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 project configured to use Entity Framework 5, backed by a SQL Server database.

One of the stored procedures in my DB performs an illegal operation: it tries to insert a `NULL` value into a `NOT NULL` column. Understandably, this fails.

Inexplicably, Entity Framework (or some other component of my ASP.NET MVC stack, or perhaps my SQL Server database) then **drops the stored procedure** from the database!

A screenshot of the error message I receive when I attempt to call my stored procedure is below:

[image: The error page displayed]

I can't seem to find any documentation on this behaviour.

**Why is this happening, and what can I do to prevent stored procedures from being dropped?**

Comment: I don't know why it's happening, but I would start by using SQL Profile to gather more information about which application or process is dropping the procedure

Comment: I am not familiar with this, but if you don't have any explicit DROP command for your statement it maybe a security option of the framework to prevent hacking?

Answer (score -1):

Use Sql profiler.

As well as simple solution

Make your column to accept Null values :)

Comment: Re-iterating a comment without adding value -1